# list AWS secrets and then iterate returning each secret value

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, async-await, azure-functions

The task is an Azure Function App that runs as a Timer Trigger that retrieves all AWS secrets with a specific Tag, then list those secrets. The code works,

1. I can retrieve SecretId with a specific tag, but I want it to get the secret values.
2. I can get the secret value if I hard code the SecretId.

I believe it is a nested asynch function issue.

```
module.exports = async function awsconnect(context, accessKey, accessSecret) {

    // Load the AWS SDK
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
        params = {
            Filters: [
                {
                  Key: "tag-key",
                  Values: [
                    'AZ_PIPELINE',
                  ]
                },
              ]
            };

    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: accessKey,
        secretAccessKey: accessSecret,
        region: "ap-southeast-2",
      });

    // Create a Secrets Manager client
    var client = new AWS.SecretsManager();

    let listSecret = await listAwsSecrets(context, client, params)

}

async function listAwsSecrets(context, client, params) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        client.listSecrets(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                context.log('Error getting credentials', err);
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                data.SecretList.forEach(function (item) {                 
                    const secret = client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: item.Name }).promise();
                    context.debug('Id=', item.Name, secret);
                });
                return resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If I run the above code in Kudu. I get the following

```
AWSConnect timer trigger function ran! 2022-03-08T04:27:09.048Z
Id= S3_SIT Promise { <pending> }
Id= App-SIT-V2 Promise { <pending> }
Id= APP-JOHN_DOE-V2 Promise { <pending> }
```

The three Secret_Ids above has the matching tag. The "pending" indicates a synch issue. But if I put await in front as per

```
const secret = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: item.Name }).promise();
```

It tells me that *await is only valid in async function*, I also get this error if I wrap this line in a async function.

So stepping back, how do I call listSecrets that matches a specific tag and get the secret value for each secretId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the code to work as follows: Use the .then.catch to list the SecretIds and then await/promise to get the secrets for each Id.

```
        listAwsSecrets(client, params).then(function (data) {
            data.SecretList.forEach(async (item) => {                 
                const secret = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: item.Name }).promise();
                console.log('Id=', item.Name, secret);
            });
        }).catch(err=> {
        console.log("Error listing secrets", err);
        })
}


function listAwsSecrets(client, params) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        client.listSecrets(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try by changing the following lines of code:

```
data.SecretList.forEach(function (item) {                 
    const secret = client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: item.Name }).promise();
    context.debug('Id=', item.Name, secret);
});
```

to

```
data.SecretList.forEach(async function (item) {                 
    const secret = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: item.Name });
    context.debug('Id=', item.Name, secret);
});
```

or

```
for (let i=0; i<data.SecretList.length; i++) {
  const item = data.SecretList[i];
  const secret = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: item.Name });
  context.debug('Id=', item.Name, secret);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that I'm using a function in forEach. Kudu is showing it correctly but when it is running as a Timer Function App, it's not waiting for listAwsSecrets. I'll give you the votes but I'm going to leave this question open for now and then post the solution when I fix listAwsSecrets